# What software is used here to compress jpeg?

Tags: compression, jpeg

https://compressjpeg.com/

The copression level is pretty inpressive, and I would like to use that encoder (or something similar) offline.

Answer (score 0):

That site doesn't do something magic to "better compress" a JPEG.
It simply opens the JPEG and saves it again at a lower quality setting
This can (sometimes greatly) reduce the size of the file, but at a cost of image quality.
On some images this can lead to a quite noticeable loss in quality, while on other images it can be nearly invisible.

Simply loading a JPG in your image-editor of choice and saving it at a lower quality setting will achieve exactly the same result, without having to upload and download your image to a web-site.
(And nobody knows what else that site is doing with the images you uploaded to them. They have a disclaimer at the bottom they will delete everything after 1 hour, but then I'm thinking that an hour is quite long and what do they do with them in the meantime?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should've added in the starting post that I compared a conversion sample of that site with FastStone Photo Resizer and the difference is very significant. The site preserved more quality with lower file size. AND it somehow automatically

Comment: AND it somehow automatically sets the appropriate quality for each photo...

Comment: It is possible. But I think you will find that you lost more color-quality and fine detail than you think, if you really look closely. From a distance it may look quite acceptable but the human eye is often a bad judge. A better method is usually to print both images to a color-printer using the same printer settings. The print-out exaggerates subtle changes that are not that obvious when seen on a screen. (Has to do with the screen being actively lighted from the back and paper is passive. Our eyes are less sensitive when looking directly at a light-source.)